80’ UK Sci-fi/Horror show about an alien invasion in the UK
I have a distant memory of a TV show that absolutely terrified me as a kid. I feel like Ive had this memory my entire life and never known what show/film it was. I know it’s possibly English and it was late 70’s early 80’s.
There’s possibly an alien invasion has happened in the UK and there’s like aliens wearing English cop uniforms on some kinda open top moon buggy transporter thing looking very white and they search a house covered in cobwebs.
I remember a fella (possibly homeless looking with a woolly hat on) knocking on a door then when the door opens he looks very shocked as he opens his coat (it’s like a long trench coat?) to see his ribs all exposed with gross skin handing off and all that.

Those "alien cops" had human faces or they looked different?

"English cop uniforms" as in Bobbies with their bobby hats? Do you recall other circumstances suggesting the UK? Was your TV set color or B&W? If color, was the show in B&W?

They were wearing 80’s British police uniforms as far as I can remember, I seem to remember a female officer too. Yeah, they had human faces, I remember them driving down a street or avenue which looked like generic English suburbs.

Although you've muddled the details, I'm sure this is They Came from Somewhere Else
Starts with a scene  of two "aliens" in a moon buggy  that explore a dusty house.  They aren't dressed as policemen, but the very next scene features a British police woman.
Homeless looking guy arrives at  19m45s
Opens his coat at 24m21s.  It isn't ribs exposed, it's a blood-soaked  shirt.  However, his insides are exposed much later, in part 6.




Oh my gosh!! Watching it now on YouTube!! Lord knows why it scared me so much.

Thank you so much, I can live my life in peace. Thank you again!!!

You're welcome. Please click on the check mark next to my answer to mark it as correct.

All done, thanks again Pete. Legend.
